# AWS Cloudfront rewrites CSS and JS references in index.html to index_files/style.css instead of css/style.css

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have the following setup:

- S3 bucket where Website hosting is enabled, "block all access" default feature is disabled. In the bucket I have an index.html file a css and a js folder with some files. I referencing them in the HTML code like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="index_files/style.css">` and  `<script src="js/somejsfile.js"></script>`. I haven't made any of the objects public directly. The bucket name is mydomain.com (I also have a [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) and s0ubqconfigured as website enabled resdirecting everything to mydomain.com bucket)
- I have a single certificate with all the cname included (naked, www, sub1). Certificate is validated using Route53
- I have created a Cloudfront distribution.

  - Origin Domain Name points to mydomain.com.s3.amazonaws.com
  - Origin Path was left empty
  - Restrict Bucket Access: yes
  - Created new Identity
  - Allowed Cloudfront to Update bucket policy (I verified later that the policy indeed was modified)
  - Alternate Domain Names: listed all 3 domains
  - Custom SSL certificate --> used the previously created cert
  - default root object: index.html
  - redirect HTTP to HTTPS
  - everything else is default
- Route 53 alias for the cloudformation dns entry.

The problem:
The site seems completely broken both on mydomain.com and the cloudformation url. After checking the page source in Firefox it turnes out that somehow all the CSS and JS reference got overwritten like `href="index_files/some-css-file.css"` and `src="index_files/some-js-file.js"`. I have no clue where this `index_files` comes from. I have double checked on S3, downloaded my index.html and the code does not have this index_files nonsense.

I used Firefox Web Developer tool to overwrite temporarly `index_files` to `css` and `js` and the sites load as it should be...

What am I missing? And where this index_files stuff comes from? My google-fu fails me on this one.

Edit/Update:

- I used the AWS Console to configure everything so no terraform or cloudformation or even aws cli is involved. (this was supposed to be a fast PoC)
- The content in S3 was copied there using S3 sync. Original content comes from a website which I `httrack`-ed (basically downloaded all the static content of the site)

BTW today I have checked the site again and it is working. No clue why. My modifications:

- I have added new origins to the distribution using same settings but with the www and the sub1 S3 buckets as soruce (so now the distributiuon has 3 origin). I don't know why would this fix it, since those S3 buckets are empty and I was always testing the site using the naked mydomain.com.
- I have added a CORS rule to the bucket to allow `"*"` and all GET methods. But since all the files in the same naked domain s3 bucket I don't know why whould this fix the issue.

So the usual meme:

- my stuff is not working... Why?
- my stiff is working... But why?

Comment: which framework you are using ? because CloudFront don't do any thing they just server object as it and cached object. difficult to help without seeing actual problem.

Comment: I have edited the original post with additional info